# ember.js and mongoDB find object by id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ember.js

Cheers!
I get Foo (for example) object from remote server with an ID, which looks like this:

```
id: "5110e8b5a8fefe71e0000197"
```

But when I do:

```
App.Foo.find("5110e8b5a8fefe71e0000197")
```

it returns array of objects, which is wrong, 'cause all ID's are uniq in mongo.

```
> Array[112]
```

So, how to make it work?

**UPDATE:**
My find function:

```
App.Foo.reopenClass({
  allFoos: [],
  find: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://address/foos.json',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      context: this,
      success: function(data){
        data.forEach(function(foo){
          this.allFoos.addObject(App.Foo.create(foo))
        }, this)
      }
    })
    return this.allFoos;
  }
});
```

Comment: #1) `find` is async, so the return `this.allFoos` is returning misleading results (as it would be the results from a previous, if any, execution of the ajax call). You'll need to add your Rails code at this point. Have you looked at the network trace in your web browser to see what the web server is returning to your JavaScript client?

Comment: It returns JSON file with Foo and it's id.

Comment: What is the server side code that's processing this request and actually doing the mongo query?

Comment: Just mongoid with mongodb and usual Rails serializer. Can't get access to back-end code right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
App.Foo.findOne({_id: "5110e8b5a8fefe71e0000197"})
```

Comment: how about App.Foo.findOne({_id: "5110e8b5a8fefe71e0000197"})

Comment: `TypeError: Object App.Foo has no method 'findOne'`

Comment: try `find({_id: "5110e8b5a8fefe71e0000197"}).fetch():`

Comment: Foo no method 'fetch', I hate you, Mongo.

Comment: I should have asked before: what is App.Foo? Is this being run on the client? The method I mentioned was for the mongodb driver server side (thinking you were hitting a nodejs express service or something)

Comment: It's an object that I recieve as JSON from Rails back-end.

Comment: @Nikita - you'll need to edit your question to include more details. What does the find JavaScript method do? What does it call on the server, etc. I would suggest you need find to make an Ajax call to your rails app which can take the id and respond with json using the ruby driver.